# How to make a long menu scroll horizontally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a long menubar in my site and it ruins the layout. I'm wondering using jQuery(or one of it's lightweight plugins), how do I hide some of the menu links and have small arrow links that allows to scroll them? Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you have a url to that site?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at the [jQuery accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this [scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html) jQuery plugin is what you're looking for.

It supports scrolling with arrow buttons, along with mouse wheel and keyboard arrows.